# source code location for debugging multiple instance of an application

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, g++, multi-user

Hi have an application running separateley (1 instance for customer) in different folders, 1 per each customer.

Each customer is a separate user on my machine.

At the moment I have the source code in each of these folders where I rebuild the code per each instance. Would it be better if I do something like the following?

1. create a shared folder where I build the code
2. deploy the binary in each user folder.
3. allow permission for each user to access the source code in READ ONLY mode.
4. when it is time to debug, by using `gdb` in each user folder will allow to read the source code and debug will happen.

Do you think that this could be a better approach or there are better practice?

My only concern is that each user has the chance to read the source code, but since the user will not access directly his folder (it is in my control) this should not trouble me.

I am using CENTOS 6.4, SVN and G++/GDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> in different folders

There are no "folders" on UNIX, they are called *directories*.

> I rebuild the code per each instance

Why would you do that?

Is the code identical (it sounds like it is)? If so, build the application *once*. There is *no reason* at all to have multiple copies of the resulting binary, or the sources.

If you make the directory with sources and binaries world-readable, then every user will be able to debug it independently.

Comment: Ok. Got it! I need to rearrange the whole but I wanted to have someking of best practice/reassurement.